# Autofocusing Ionic 3 AlertController inputs

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to get the first input in an Ionic 3 alert to focus when the alert is created. I have been able to get the input to focus when running the app in a browser, but it doesn't work on a native device.

**What I've tried:**

I found a solution [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/set-focus-on-input-inside-alert-prompt/51885/7) which uses `document.querySelector()` to find the first input and focus it. However, this only works when running in a browser; when running on a native device, nothing happens- no cursor, no keyboard, nothing.

Any insights into how to make this work?

```
alert.present().then(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const firstInput: any = document.querySelector('ion-alert input');
    firstInput.focus();
  }, 200)
  return;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution (and discovered that Ionic actually will autofocus the first input if you make this change, without any need to use `document.querySelector`!)

In `config.xml`, I needed to add the following key. I recompiled the app and the first input now focuses.

`<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />`